# Jquery Toggling Between Two Different Divs On Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, toggle

How can I disable a jquery function using an if else statement.
My problem is that I have two text boxes that open onClick, they are set to toggle, but how can I set it so that if one of the boxes is open, the other one won't open
 My jquery is

```
$(".first1").on('click', 
  function () {
    $('#suitsyou').toggle();
  });
$(".last1").on('click', 
  function () {
      $('#dealsandoffers').toggle() 
  });
```

It may be easier to look at my website http://www.jeremyspence.net78.net it is in the packages tab, you can see that when you click on one tab and then the other without closing the first they both open

the html is

```
    <div id="suitsyou" style="display:none">

    </div>

    <div id="dealsandoffers" style="display:none"> 

    </div>
```

Content was not included so not to put so much code in

Comment: please provide html within your question, link to site may change in future rendering this question useless to future readers, and is not intuitive going to site as to what the problem is. The ideal would be to provide a simple demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional should work:

```
$(".first").on('click', function () {
    if (!$("#dealsandoffers:visible").length) {
        $("#suitesyou").toggle();
    }
});
```

Use classes if you need more flexibility than that.  This also isn't particularly user friendly.  Seems to me like you would want to close the other and then show the one that was currently clicked.

Comment: That's what I thought to do at first too, but when I put it in (like it is now) only the second one works, the first box doesn't show, you can see it at  http://www.jeremyspence.net78.net

Comment: the reason why this wasn't working is that you spelt suits wrong and I copy and pasted it but it works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without changing to much, you could simply show the correct one and then hide the other, toggling between work work great.  Although I have to admit, its not an elegant solution but if this is what you're going for, it should do the trick.

```
$(".first1").on('click', 
  function () {
   $('#dealsandoffers').hide()
    $('#suitsyou').show();
  });
$(".last1").on('click', 
  function () {
      $('#suitsyou').hide()
      $('#dealsandoffers').show() 
  });
```

Comment: That works to an extent, if you click on both though it is impossible to make it go away

Comment: How do you click on both? Last I read most people have one mouse.

Answer (score 0):

[Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills), you are right on about how to toggle two different DIVs on a button click. As you stated,

> Seems to me like you would want to close the other and then show the one that was currently clicked.

To do this you simply need to apply the jQuery toggle to both views. In my solution, I placed a Toggle button with the ID of "btnToggle" and then added the two div tags like so. It is important to not that the alternate view "lastView" has a style of display: none. This allows the initial state of the alternate view to begin as invisible.

I hope this proves to be helpful and thank you for the headstart on solving my question.

```js
$("#btnToggle").on('click', function() {
  $("#firstView").toggle();
  $("#lastView").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnToggle" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Views</button>

<div id="firstView">
  <h2>First View</h2>
  <p>I am the default view. I will be displayed when the view renders.</p>
  <p>Then I will gracefully hide when the toggle button is clicked.</p>
</div>

<div id="lastView" style="display: none">
  <h2>Alternate View</h2>
  <p>I am the alternate view. I will be quietly standing by invisible until the toggle button is clicked.</p>
</div>
```