# Toggle between two sets of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have two paragraphs of text on a webpage and would like only one of them to be visible at a time.  Ideally, I would like to achieve this through a set of buttons at the top of the page, possibly through javascript or jquery?

EDIT:  I am currently working with the following code.  Everything is visible, the button is 'clickable' but nothing happens when I click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>What OCA should do next</h1>

<div id='Content'>
<div id='1'><p>THIS IS TEXT 1</p></div>
<div id='2' style='display:none;'><p>THIS IS DEFINITELY NOT TEXT 1</p></div>
</div>

<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
<script>
var shown = 1;
$("#Submit").click(function() {
   if(shown == 1) {
      $("#text1").css("display", "none");
      $("#text2").css("display", "block");
      shown = 2;
   } 
   else {
      $("#text2").css("display", "none");
      $("#text1").css("display", "block");
      shown = 1;
   }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A bit more search would have given you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720054/jquery-toggling-between-two-different-divs-on-button-click

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't put lengthy code in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I only posted after a lengthy search in which I only found answers for premade translation toggles, which was not what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

You can place them in different divs inside of a content div and show them at separate times:

```
<div id='Content'>
   <div id='text1'><p>THIS IS TEXT 1 </p></div>
   <div id='text2' style='display:none;'><p>THIS IS DEFINITELY NOT TEXT 1 </p></div>
</div>
<a id='changeText'>CHANGE</a>
<!-- Style the <a> To make it look like a button -->
<script>
   var shown = 1;
   $("#changeText").click(function() {
       if(shown == 1) {
          $("#text1").css("display", "none");
          $("#text2").css("display", "block");
          shown = 2;
       } else {
          $("#text2").css("display", "none");
          $("#text1").css("display", "block");
          shown = 1;
       }
   });
</script>
```

I hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: This looks good, and I can see in the code that it should do what I need it to do.  Unfortunately, the button doesn't seem to work when I preview it.

Comment: Try using the edit I just made

Comment: Thank you.  I had a go, but I still can't get it to work properly.  Please see above for the new edit.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You made a syntax error as far as I can see: If you want to check things, you have to use comparison operators such as: == != >= <= etc. What you're doing is this: `if(shown = 1) {` which is an assignment operator. Try changing it to: `if(shown == 1) {` that should help.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the change as suggested, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.  I have changed my code in the original to post to reflect this.  Any further help you could offer me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ahh I missed it: you're using a submit button to call the click function, and you call it by id (that's where `#Submit` stands for). To call it you could change the button: `<button type='submit' value='Submit' id='Submit'>Submit</button>` That way you should be able to call it :)